# Can dplyr automatically generate a column with merge results after join operations?

Tags: r, dplyr, merge

This might seem a somewhat basic question, but after reviewing documentation and searching the Internet I couldn't find an answer to this.

My question is: does R's `dplyr` include an argument to automatically generate a column with merge results after joining two dataframes? With join operations I mean `left_join`, `right_join`, or `full_join`.

I'm thinking of something similar to the `_merge` column you can generate on Python's `pandas` with the argument `indicator = True` when using `merge`, or to Stata's `_merge` variable that is generated by default using the `merge` command.

For example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = c(1,2), value1 =  c(1,1))
df2 <- data.frame(id = c(1,3), value2 =  c(2,1))
result <- df1 %>% full_join(df2, by = 'id', merge_results_option = TRUE)
# Notice that merge_results_option is the argument I'm looking for with this question, if it exists
```

Should yield:

```
|--------------|---------------|--------------|--------------|
|      id      |     value1    |    value2    |    _merge    |
|--------------|---------------|--------------|--------------|
|       1      |       1       |       2      |   both       |
|       2      |       1       |       NA     |   left       |
|       3      |       NA      |       1      |   right      |
|--------------|---------------|--------------|--------------|
```

Comment: This question would be a lot clearer if you gave a short reproducible example. Could you show 2 sample input data frames with 3 rows each and also your desired result?

Comment: thanks, now it's updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is implemented, more-or-less, by the [`tidylog` package](https://github.com/elbersb/tidylog). It prints a message summarizing the number of matches, but does add a column identifying each row.

You can read the discussion on the [`dplyr` Feature request here](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2183), which lead to the development of `tidylog`, which ended with

> Given that `tidylog` has solved this problem so wonderfully, I no longer think this needs to be in `dplyr`

though some users were still dissatisfied with lack of the column-add functionality. Surprisingly, I didn't see that feature request in the [tidylog issues](https://github.com/elbersb/tidylog/issues), so maybe you could add it there.

Answer (score 1):

As already said, I don't think this is a functionality of dplyr. Interestingly it's not something that is used in SQL either where joins are very common. However, the column can be recreated using mutate:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = c(1,2), value1 =  c(1,1))
df2 <- data.frame(id = c(1,3), value2 =  c(2,1))


result <- df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = 'id') %>% 
  mutate(merge = case_when(!is.na(value1) & !is.na(value2) ~ "both",
                       !is.na(value1) & is.na(value2) ~ "left",
                       is.na(value1) & !is.na(value2) ~ "right",
                       TRUE ~ "missing"
                       ))
```